# Using Ajax with Cookies

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, cross-domain, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create a drag and drop interface for my website that integrates with Imgur. The problem is that I am trying to use ajax with cookies. I have gotten it to work without signing in, but I need the pictures to be under my account. In theory my code should work, but in practice for some reason the ajax requests/cookies aren't working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks :D

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/msm595/9arFd/
My username and password aren't in there (although i was testing with a dummy account anyway).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Requests_with_credentials

You are using cross domain plus credentials. Then the server has to response with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://jsfiddle.net/msm595/9arFd/
```

and not with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Wildcards are not allowed in this case.
You may want to test with Chrome, it shows both headers and gave me this message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.imgur.com/2/signin. Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.`
```

That's all I can say, imgur has to explicitly allow your JS solution. You may need a piece of code running on server's side not having cross domain issues.